# unsupoorted operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, integer

My code is basically

```
brith_year= input("Please enter the year you was born in: ")
age= (2021 - brith_year
print("You're " + age + "year old!")
```

yet the error is > unsupoorted operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: missing a ')' at the end of the age line, also, the input will probably be a string. I'll leave a correction in the answer section.

Comment: Then you should convert `birth_year` to integer `birth_year = int(birth_year)`

Comment: what part of that error message is confusing?

Answer (score 1):

```py
brith_year= int(input("Please enter the year you was born in: "))
age= str(2021 - brith_year)
print("You're " + age + "years old!")
```

Things to keep in mind here:
2021 is an int, and when you call input() birth_year will be a string so the int - string will cause an error.  That's why we convert birth year to an int first.

The same problem happens in the print statement:
"You're" is a string but age is now an int, so we need to convert age back to a string so that we can concatenate the two.

---

**Edit:**

@Ramez-Khaled made a good recommendation:

```py
brith_year= int(input("Please enter the year you was born in: "))
age= 2021 - brith_year
print(f"You're {age} year old!")
```

Using a f-string is generally much cleaner and this solution is the better of the two.  For a beginner though, the explicitness of the top solution may be more appropriate.

Comment: No need to typecast age here.

Comment: yes @Nk03, you need to.  It won't concatenate `int` when printing without it.  Alternately you could do `print("You're "  + str(age) + "years old!")`

Comment: Ohh I missed it. @JD2775

Answer (score 0):

By default, python reads the data as a string, while you want it to be an int. The error here is you are trying to subtract a string from an integer which is impossible. The simplest solution will be:

```
brith_year= int(input("Please enter the year you was born in: "))
```

Using an integer constructor to convert the string into integer